# Obtain road type from nominatim

Tags: geocoding, openstreetmap, nominatim

Is there a way of obtaining the type of road an object is settled in from a request via nominatim?

**For example**

http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=xml&lat=52.5487429714954&lon=-1.81602098644987&zoom=18&addressdetails=1

does provide me with loads of info. yet, there is no info on the road the address is settled in. would like to obtain something like: rural road or even just grade*N* (where *N* stands for the level of hierarchy.) i hope what i'm looking for is understandable :) thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nominatim is for searching *addresses*, you probably want to use the [OverpassAPI](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) to query roads around the given coordinates:

```
http://overpass.osm.rambler.ru/cgi/interpreter?data=[out:json];way[highway](52.52,-1.82,52.55,-1.81);out;
```

Then choose the one matching your coordinates the best and look at the *highway=* value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`format=jsonv2`** instead of `format=xml` or `format=json`.

`format=jsonv2` adds the next fields to response: `place_rank`,**`category`**, **`type`**,`importance`, `addresstype`.

I added this information to [Nominatim Reverse Geocoding documentation.](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Reverse_Geocoding)

When category tag contains value **`highway`** the **`type`** tag shows the road type.

Find more information about `highway types` at [OpenStreetMap highway tag](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:highway)